# Rails 6.1 sass-loader without asset pipeline (webpacker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, sass-loader, sass-globbing

## Auto-including all nested SCSS files with Rails 6.1 and sass-loader

With Rails 6.0.3.4 it was possible to use Sass-loader to glob all SCSS files without including each and every one manually.

### Problem - syntax v7

This fails in Rails 6.1 with the following webpacker error (with webpacker config, see below, `.options = { importer: globImporter() }; // syntax for sass-loader v7`)

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/packs/application.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'importer'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (/workspace/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:98:11)
    at Object.loader (/workspace/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:36:28)
```

### Problem - syntax v8

If I change the config to sass-loader v8 syntax (`.sassOptions = { importer: globImporter() };`), I get different error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].use[3] has an unknown property 'sassOptions'. These properties are valid:
   object { ident?, loader?, options?, query? }
```

### Question

How to configure it with Rails 6.1 and sass-loader v8?

## Original pre 6.1 working config:

1. `yarn add node-sass-glob-importer`, Rails 6.1 uses `sass-loader@8.0.2`
2. Adjust webpack configuration to pass loader options:

```js
# config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

environment
    .loaders
    .get('sass')
    .use
    .find(item => item.loader === 'sass-loader')
    .options = { importer: globImporter() }; // syntax for sass-loader v7
    // .sassOptions = { importer: globImporter() }; // for v8

module.exports = environment
```

3. Then in

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.scss
import './application.scss';
```

4. and finally in

```css
// app/javascript/packs/application.scss
@import '../stylesheets/**/*.scss';
```

All nested SCSS stylesheets under `app/javascript/packs` would then be automatically globbed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. For Rails 6.1 you need the following `environment.js` webpacker configuration:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

environment
    .loaders
    .get('sass')
    .use
    .find(item => item.loader === 'sass-loader')
    .options = { sassOptions: { importer: globImporter() } }; // <-- this!

module.exports = environment
```